# Vue.js and Express Templating

Tags: express, vue.js

I've spent a lot of time trying to inject variable to vue.js pages I have from a web server built on Express.

Basically I want to have a http end point on express that will get a parameter which I will then use to get more information from my db and inject it in a vue.js page I will serve.

For example, the endpoint will look like this:

/page/:page_id

And I will then use page_id to get information about the page and place it as vue.js variables so I can use it on the page.

The only lib I could find for this is something called express-vue - but it doesn't seem to be very stable.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You should use a HTTP library like Axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to get the data and then use that data in your component.

Comment: So I get the "page_id" from the url through the browser? Is that a common practice?

Comment: Yes, you use the ID in the URL, but not though the browser (although you could), but like this: var userID=23; axios.get('/page/' + userID)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Comment: Wait, I need the to work with a link, how do you get "var userID=23"?

Comment: That depends on your project. In the projects I works what we do is ususally have an endpoint that get a list of items that included the IDs of the object, then when the user selects an item of that list I use the object's ID

Comment: But say that there is no page before. You just want a link of the page that you will open. So once you open it, the client needs to get the id from somewhere so it could query the server. If not from the browser (through window.location.href) then from where?